# Pagination not displaying

Tags: php, functions, pagination

I'm using HTML5Blank theme to edit my own theme on clean basis, and trying to set the pagination but it's not displaying for some reason, and I cant find out why.

Index.php calls loop then pagination templates

```
<section>
    <?php get_template_part('loop'); ?>

    <?php get_template_part('pagination'); ?>
</section>
```

Pagination.php calls pagination function

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php html5wp_pagination(); ?>
</div>
```

The function is

```
// Pagination for paged posts, Page 1, Page 2, Page 3, with Next and  Previous Links, No plugin
function html5wp_pagination()
{
global $wp_query;
$big = 999999999;
echo paginate_links(array(
    'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link($big)),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max(1, get_query_var('paged')),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
));
}
```

I haven't touched anything related to the pagination, and I can see that the `<div class="pagination">` is called in the HTML using Chrome console, but is not displaying anything.

I thought this could be because I had not enough post to display the pagination, but I tried to add a lot of posts, and it's still not showing.

Any idea of what is the problem ?

Comment: Are you sure you have more posts than the "Blog pages show at most" setting under Settings > Reading?

Comment: Do `echo $wp_query->max_num_pages;` in your template and check what it returns

Answer (score -1):

You need to add **your query variable** to the **global used on the function**, in that case "**$wp_query**", just like that:

```
<?php
  $yourQuery_args = ['posts_per_page' => '7',];
  $yourQuery = new WP_Query( $yourQuery_args );

  $wp_query = $yourQuery;
  get_template_part('pagination'); 
?>
```